# Google Analytics API - ga:productSku returns "message":"Login Required" and null gaData.getRows()

Tags: google-analytics

Issue summary:
I try to get analytics with dimension ga:productSku. I obtain gaData.getRows()=null and Self link: https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:3294251&dimensions=ga:productSku&metrics=ga:bounces&start-date=2015-07-14&end-date=2015-07-14
which means particularly: {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"required","message":"Login Required","locationType":"header","location":"Authorization"}],"code":401,"message":"Login Required"}}

Steps to reproduce issue:
1. I use next auth data:
AccountId : 1824981
"username":"446368808773-74sbv0i61c3oeoercuta781vfr69gi32@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
profileId: 3294251
"name":"www.e96.ru"
2. I use next java-code:
        String ids = "ga:" + profileId;
        String startDate = GA_DATE_FORMAT.format(date);
        String endDate = startDate;
        String dimensions = "ga:productSku";
        String metrics = "ga:bounces";
        Get apiQuery = analytics.data().ga()
                .get(ids, startDate, endDate, metrics)
                .setDimensions(dimensions);
3.

Expected output:
What do you expect to see after performing the above steps? - I expect to obtain populated object gaData.getRows();

Actual results:
What do you actually see after performing the above steps? - I obtain gaData.getRows()=null and Self link: https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:3294251&dimensions=ga:productSku&metrics=ga:bounces&start-date=2015-07-14&end-date=2015-07-14
which means particularly: {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"required","message":"Login Required","locationType":"header","location":"Authorization"}],"code":401,"message":"Login Required"}}

What should I do to get correct SKU data?

Comment: Have tried working through the steps of the Hello Analytics API tutorials? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-java